# Center the background position of body / div to middle of Viewport

Tags: javascript

I have a Body height of 1000px, and my screen height is 100px. I wanted to display a `<div>` that occupies the entire `<body>` width and `<body>` height. That `<div>` is having one `background-image` and I want to make it displayed at the middle of the viewport. How can I achieve this using Javascript.

I have used the below concept but it did not work for me in mobile devices

```
  ele.style.backgroundPosition = document.body.scrollTop + 
                                 (window.innerHeight / 2) - heightOfImage;
```

Comment: Which mobile devices are you targeting specifically?

Comment: @vee all HTML5 aand CSS3 suppported devices

Comment: The background-position CSS property can take in two parameters, like so: 'background-position: [horizontal] [vertical]'. If you only specify one parameter (as in your example) it will only set the horizontal scroll positions (leaving the vertical position at 50%). Are you simply trying to center the image vertically, or do you actually want it to always display in the middle of the viewport even if the user scrolls down the page?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be middle of the viewport even if I scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution may be to have a fixed positioned `<div />` with the background image set on it, and it's z-index set such that it appears under all the other elements on the page.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gztRa/

If you really do want to go the JavaScript route (which I personally wouldn't do if I could help it here), you're going to have to do something along these lines:

1. Hook up to the scroll event of the element thats scrolling
2. Every time this fires, adjust the scroll position like so:

`var verticalPosition = document.body.scrollTop + (window.innerHeight / 2) - heightOfImage;`

`ele.style.backgroundPosition = 'center ' + verticalPosition  + 'px';`

Note the addition of the `'px'` as this is important. There is also a space after "center", so you should end up with something that looks like this: `ele.style.backgroundPosition = 'center 50px'`.

Example (using Zepto or jQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/7aqgG/7/